How to execute multiple API calls in parallel and process responses as they arrive in an HTTP service in Angular?
I have an HTTP service that receives responses which need to be utilized by multiple other APIs. I want to execute these API calls in parallel. Additionally, I do not want to wait for all the APIs to complete execution; instead, I want to process each API's response as soon as it is received.
Here's what I am trying to achieve:

My primary HTTP service receives a response.
This response needs to be passed to multiple other APIs.
These APIs should be called in parallel.
As soon as one API responds, I want to immediately process its data without waiting for the others.

search(metaInfo: Interface1, searchDetails: Interface2) {
    return this.http.post<Interface3>(API_ROUTES.history, metaInfo)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((res) => {
        return combineLatest([
          this.http.post<any>(API_ROUTES.searchOne, {...searchDetails, requestId: res.requestId}),
          this.http.post<any>(API_ROUTES.searchTwo, {...searchDetails, requestId: res.requestId})
        ])
      })
    )
  }

Is there any rxjs operator which can be used in place of combineLatest or forkJoin so that I can subscribe to responses as they arrives and don't have to wait for both the request to finish.
P.S.: First API execution time 1 sec , Second API execution time 30-40 sec so can't wait for both the API's to complete execution

Have you tried with forkJoin?

forkJoin also waits for the completion of all.

Oh. Right, I totally misread that. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip, then?

Try merge of rxjs
Why use merge?

The merge operator is your go-to solution when you have multiple observables that produce values independently and you want to combine their output into a single stream. Think of it as a highway merger, where multiple roads join together to form a single, unified road - the traffic (data) from each road (observable) flows seamlessly together.

search(metaInfo: Interface1, searchDetails: Interface2) {
    return this.http.post<Interface3>(API_ROUTES.history, metaInfo)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((res) => {
        return merge(
          this.http.post<any>(API_ROUTES.searchOne, {...searchDetails, requestId: res.requestId}),
          this.http.post<any>(API_ROUTES.searchTwo, {...searchDetails, requestId: res.requestId})
        )
      })
    )
  }

One important note, you need to use the next block of subscribe so it will look like
this.search.subscribe({
    next: () => {
        // processing logic here!
    }
});

